# How to link images with records from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My site is having much profiles, each profile has a  few images. Users upload this images themselves. I need to link images from disk and profiles in MySQL table. Tell me  best way to realize this functionality for more flexibility?

ps I'm using CodeIgniter 2 + MySQL.

Comment: Can you please give more information regarding your current upload structure? E.g. Are all images being uploaded to a shared directory or are you creating a folder per user they going to?

Comment: All iamges upload in one folder, with unique name.

Comment: @NiLL's suggestion makes sense. Or store the path to the image along with the user record.

Comment: Now, I create two table profile and images. First has a field photo. Second table stores unique id and link to image. But I don't know how link profile with many images.

Comment: @NiLL Use a common key to do this, for example the images table may have 'user_id' that relates back to a 'user_id' column stored in the user table. This way when you query you just make suer you specify the owner in that query. Keep in mind that I don't know your DB structure so the field names are just as an example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing this now, but it non-flexible :-(

Comment: you can use time() with your image name to get uniqueness. i.e $file_name .= time().$file_name;

Comment: store the images in directories and store the name , path of the image, to whom the image belongs , ip address from which the image is uploaded ,etc in a databse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using CodeIgniter.
I assume that you are using the File Uploading Class.

After successful completion of upload, you can use

```
$this->upload->data()
```

Which basically returns an array which contains all the data related to the upload.
example array

```
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

Its better to store these details into database, along with the user ID to which the image belongs.
And when you want to retrieve the images, just make query where the user id = someint ..

I think this solution is better than storing images in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial for storing images in MySQL using PHP:

http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/6937-tutorial-storing-images-mysql-php.html

Comment: Why do this? It just means you need to unnecessarily hit your database every time an image is requested.

Comment: Bas practice, stores files in BLOB are very expensive and slow.

Comment: I agree for larger images, but I think for something small like a profile picture this would work just fine. Plus it feels more secure than giving the user the ability to upload files that are served up by a web application.  Also it simplifies backup, and encapsulates the app data a little more cleanly than a file system solution.

Comment: You're convinced me, it could be works with small count of data.

Comment: Storing images in DB is not a good idea. Use disk space to store images and put the name of images into DB. Your DB will not be overloaded in future.

Comment: @GitsD - You know, you could always add your own answer rather than making blanket unsupported assertions as comments on this one.

Comment: @john i said "in future"...please read my comment. You said for small size images BLOB is good (I agree) but in future DB will be overloaded.

Comment: How do you figure the DB will be overloaded in the future? What exactly do you mean by "overloaded"?